# FreeRADIUS Rest Module on Centos 6.x

Tags: freeradius, json

I am attempting to add JSON support for the REST module on Centos 6.5

I have installed the json-c-devel package however when compiling FreeRADIUS it complains it can't find it:

```
[root@dhcp01]# ./configure --with-dhcp --with-experimental-modules

...
...
checking for json/json.h... yes
checking for json_c_version in -ljson-c in /usr/lib64... no
checking for json_c_version in -ljson-c... no
checking for json_c_version in -ljson-c in /usr/local/lib... no
checking for json_c_version in -ljson-c in /opt/lib... no
configure: WARNING: json-c libraries not found. Use --with-jsonc-lib-dir=<path>.
configure: WARNING: silently building without JSON support. requires: json-c
...
...

[root@dhcp01 lib64]# yum install json-c-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.xnet.co.nz
 * epel: fedora.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
 * extras: centos.mirror.uber.com.au
 * remi: remi.conetix.com.au
 * updates: centos.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au
Setting up Install Process
Package json-c-devel-0.10-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I found that the JSON-C libraries are installed at /usr/lib64:

```
usr/lib64/libjson.so
usr/lib64/libjson.so.0
usr/lib64/libjson.so.0.1.0
```

But seems to be missing libjson-c.so which I think may be the problem.  I have also tried compiling specifying /usr/lib64 as the JSON-C Library path, but same outcome:

```
./configure --with-dhcp --with-experimental-modules --with-jsonc-lib-dir=/usr/lib64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use v3.0.x head, the check was modified to include the json_tokener_new symbol in its checks, which is present in older versions of JSON-C. Or if you build JSON-C from src it should be a new enough version that it'll work.

Comment: Thanks - I found an updated json-c and json-c-devel version here - http://rpms.adiscon.com/v7-stable/epel-6/x86_64/RPMS/